# Расчёт мощности железа для Java EE приложения

Tags: java, wildfly, j2ee

Как рассчитать мощность железа для интерпрайзного приложения на Java EE. В качестве сервера собираюсь использовать WildFly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задача срочная, то самое простое что могу предложить если в активе уже есть что-либо похожее:

1. Провести нагрузочное тестирование готового приложения
2. По результатам тестирования аппроксимировать данные исходя из сложности конченого приложения и разницы нагрузки на него и на текущее.

Т.е. если простыми словами, берем похожее приложение, снимаем показатели нагрузки на текущей конфигурации. К примеру, получилось что при 1000 активных сессий пользователей в течении часа нагрузка на CPU - 50%, RAM - 2гБ.
По ТЗ смотрим, что у нас будет тяжеловесных операций примерно в 2 раза меньше но нагрузка будет в 10000 пользователей. Соотвественно, нам понадобится мощности примерно в 5 раз больше. У нас проекты сильно похожие, поэтому такая оценка довольно точна, +20% или 1 резервную ноду в кластер закладываю.
По HDD - в зависимости от требований по записи на диск. При отсутствии частого файлового обмена можно взять RAID 5+1, если файлы часто пишутся , то лучше RAID10
ПО резервным нодам и бекапам - тоже в зависимости от требований по недоступности системы. Если обязательно 24/7, то закладываем не менее 2х резервных нод в разных датацентрах.
Если будет БД - не забудь сайзинг под сервер БД.

Если времени много, то для большего понимания перфоманса и сайзинга могу посоветовать книгу [Pro Java EE 5 Performance Management and Optimization By Steven Haines](http://www.apress.com/9781590596104).